# Unknown JAXB exception, nested exception is java.xml.bind.JAXBException, class not known to this context

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb

This is the first time I've worked with jaxb and XML marshalling.  There is a Utils project that has basic utilities and shared classes that two other projects Foo and Bar that depend on Utils.  What I need to do in Foo and Bar is send a message to RabbitMQ.  The message is the same between the two projects.

Can I create a service that is shared between Foo and Bar that sends the message in the Utils project that does not have any spring-context.xml file (we are using Spring).  Cause when I try that, I get the `Unknown JAXB exception, nested exception is java.xml.bind.JAXBException, class not known to this context` error.  And when I look at other projects on our team that use jaxb2 and send messages to rabbit successfully, all those individual components pull in the schema for the object to send on the bus, and all those projects have a spring-context file, and all those projects have something like

```
  <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller"
    context-path="com.my.awesome.proj" />
```

defined.  And even though I define the jaxb2-marshaller in Foo and Bar's sprint-context file, I get that error.  So I'm basically asking what the recommended approach is.  Do most projects pull in the schema of the object to send on the bus and then in each of the individual projects send out the message?

Comment: you need to add com.sun.xml.* package from external dependencies starting from Java11+

Answer (score 0):

From the exception, it appears that the message class is not added into the JaxbContext. Try instantiating

`JaxbContext.newInstance(yourMessageClassName.class)`